# Flutter: Running "flutter pub get" nothing happens

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to get packages, when I run `flutter pub get` it says a color red text I don't know what this means `! analyzer 0.38.4` and just terminated the process.

```
C:\Mobi\del_cus_app>flutter pub get
! analyzer 0.38.4
Running "flutter pub get" in del_cus_app...                         1.7s

C:\Mobi\del_cus_app>
```

I also already upgrade the flutter version

Answer (score 0):

Hello BGTabulation BGTabulate, When you trying to get package then sometime our dependency is override on another package so when this kind of issue occurs then may be you have to do like

```
dependencies:
  intl: ^0.15.0







dependency_overrides:
   intl: ^0.16.0
```

Comment: and don't worry about ! analyzer 0.38.4 in console

Answer (score 0):

Note the space character of the entered values.

```
dependencies:
  flutter_native_splash: ^0.1.9
```

Answer (score 0):

Delete `pubspec.lock` file and run `flutter pub get`

Answer (score -1):

try to using 
                 `flutter clean`   command

then close IDE and restart it again,
it happens sometimes when dart analyzer crashes.